# Adding google apis on unsigned applications

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator

Hi i am making an application and  want to add Google maps which would point to my location . My problem is that this application is till being developed and has not been signed or launched . Is it possible for me to add a Google API on an unsigned application or APK ?

Comment: Yes - the google map api key is different to your others.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can,

Your just have to create the Console API Key with debug.keystore.

See Vogella's guide: [www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)